# How to test ServerEndPoint, ClientEndPoint?

Tags: java, testing, websocket, jsr356

I have implemented `ServerEndPoint` and `ClientEndPoint`, how can i test it?
For example, i have Connection wrappers over Session and i want to test it behavior which depends on session data, also i want to test messaging between client and server.
Note that i don't have any war or any of application configuration such as web.xml, web-sockets infrastructure going to be used in another place, all what i have is mapped ServerEndPoint and ClientEndPoint implementations.

Comment: Can you post some of your code which will help it easy to see you implementation?

Answer (score 3):

The Tyrus reference implementation has a test tools package which contains a test server that can be used with a client: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.tyrus.tests/tyrus-test-tools/1.10

The samples on Github are a good usage guide: https://github.com/tyrus-project/tyrus/blob/master/archetypes/echo/src/main/resources/archetype-resources/src/test/java/EchoTest.java